# Trying to get php to output xml with full url instead of relative path

Tags: php, ios, xml, air

I have this working fine in browser but air for ios need the full address.

```
<?php $path_to_image_dir = 'Games/game_images/'.$username; 

    $xml_string = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?><data> <LoaderMax name=\"gallery\">";

    if ( $handle = opendir( $path_to_image_dir ) ) {
        $i = 1;
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ( is_file($path_to_image_dir.'/'.$file) ) {
                $xml_string .= "<ImageLoader url=\"" . $path_to_image_dir."/".$file . "\"  />";
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }


$xml_string .= "</LoaderMax></data>";
$ignore = array('.','..','cgi-bin','.DS_Store');
$file = fopen($username.'_imagesfile.xml','w');
fwrite($file, $xml_string);
fclose($file);
?>
```

---

this is the xml result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><data> <LoaderMax name="gallery"><ImageLoader url="Games/game_images/mrpeepers/1365535674.jpg"  /><ImageLoader url="Games/game_images/mrpeepers/1365535527.jpg"  /></LoaderMax></data>
```

---

works on ios if address is added by hand `http://wwww.mysite.ccom/Games/game_images/mrpeeper/1365535674.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] to your directory name like so:

```
$xml_string .= "<ImageLoader url=\"" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/" . $path_to_image_dir."/".$file . "\"  />";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Just added it like this: $xml_string .= "<ImageLoader url=\"" ."http".":". "/" . "/" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/" . $path_to_image_dir."/".$file . "\" />";